# Pyetrade / Etrade API for option-chains function only returns options for apple?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, etrade-api

I'm trying to get some option chains using the pyetrade package. I'm working in Sandbox mode for a newly made Etrade account.

When I execute the following code, it executes fine, but the returned information is incorrect: I keep getting options for Apple between 2012 and 2015, instead of current Exxon-Mobil options (what I'm inputting). This is also true for if I ask for Google or Facebook or Netflix, I just keep getting outdated Apple options.

I'm not sure where I messed up, or if this is just something that's part of sandbox mode, so that's why I asked for help. Thank you!

(Note: Some of the code is sourced from:     https://github.com/1rocketdude/pyetrade_option_chains/blob/master/etrade_option_chains.py)

The following is the function to get the option chain from the API:

```
def getOption(thisSymbol):
   #Renew session / or start session
   try:
       authManager.renew_access_token()
   except:
       authenticate() #this works fine

   #make a market object to pull what you  need from
   market = pyetrade.ETradeMarket(
       consumer_key,
       consumer_secret,
       tokens['oauth_token'],
       tokens['oauth_token_secret'],
       dev=True
   )

   try:
       #the dates returned are also 
       q = market.get_option_expire_date(thisSymbol,resp_format='xml')
       #just formats the dates to be more comprehensible:
       expiration_dates = option_expire_dates_from_xml(q)
  except Exception:
       raise

   rtn = []
   for this_expiry_date in expiration_dates:
       q = market.get_option_chains(thisSymbol, this_expiry_date)
       chains = q['OptionChainResponse']['OptionPair']
       rtn.append(chains)
   print()
   return rtn

ret = getOption("XOM")
print(ret[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API provider is explicit on this:

> **Note:**
>
> `E*TRADE`'s sandbox **doesn't actually produce correct option chains** so this will return an error.
>
> The sandbox is still useful for debugging e.g. the OAuth stuff.

No one could hardly make the *`sandbox`*-ed code work otherwise.

Comment: Always welcome ☔

Comment: I get an "Unauthorized" error when I try to use https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/market/optionchains?symbol={symbol} I don't have this problem with any other end points