# Product Key for Etrade Individual Development is Returning 401 Client Error

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, etrade-api

So a [follow up on this question, where I still have the same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669435/pyetrade-etrade-api-for-option-chains-function-only-returns-options-for-apple): to start working with some live data, I switched from sandbox to individual key, and started getting this error with code that did work in sandbox mode:

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/market/optionexpiredate?symbol=NFLX&expiryType=ALL

Here's the authentication code, in case I messed up here:

```
consumer_key = "[key, double checked]"
consumer_secret = "[secret, double checked]" 

def authenticate():
    #get the auth UIL
    oauth = pyetrade.ETradeOAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    oauth.setToken(consumer_key)
    oauth.setTokenSecret(consumer_secret)
    print(oauth.get_request_token())

    #ask the user to put the verification code in to get tokens
    verifier_code = input("Enter verification code: ")
    global tokens 
    tokens = oauth.get_access_token(verifier_code)
    print(tokens)

    #Setting up the object used for Access Management
    global authManager 
    authManager = pyetrade.authorization.ETradeAccessManager(
        consumer_key,
        consumer_secret,
        tokens['oauth_token'],
        tokens['oauth_token_secret']
    )
```

And this is the code that returns the error:

```
try:
    q = market.get_option_expire_date(thisSymbol,resp_format='xml')
    expiration_dates = option_expire_dates_from_xml(q)
except:
    raise Exception("Rip, get date not working")
```

I'm not sure why this is happening :( any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Assuming that you are using the correct secrets for the new URL, which of course we cannot verify, then it seems logical from the error, "Unauthorized for url:", that you haven't completed the paperwork to get authorized. It's been a while, but I seem to recall that they don't send you the live token until you are authorized. But I feel like we had trouble sorting that out.

Comment: Figured it out! Forgot to turn "dev = true" to "dev = false" when switching from sandbox to actual mode. This setting is in the ETradeMarket object creation parameters.